# MS Access VBA - Loop Recordsets

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am wondering if anyone could direct me to a good tutorial on how to develop loops. Basically I have a "tblmachines" with columns ID, MachineName and Checkbox. What I want to create is an on click event, VBA will take todays date and input that into "tblloop" column "LoopDate", and then add all machines in "tblmachines" which have their checkbox selected into "tblloop" column "loopMachines".

Answer (score -1):

If you're inserting records from tblmachines table to tblloop table based on the check box criteria use the below code:

```
Sub Btn_Click()
    Dim StrQry As String
    StrQry = "insert into [tblloop] ([LoopDate], [loopMachines]) select # " & VBA.Now & "# as [LoopDate], [MachineName] from [tblmachines] where Checkbox = 'True'"
    Currentdb.Execute StrQry
End Sub
```